# push_back and insert do not work properly in my own vector class

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, vector

So, here is the header file where I implemented my own vector class in a simple way. 
The problem is that even though the code compiles, the member functions pushBack and insert both do not work properly.

I'd be really glad if anyone can figure out the problem in my code or find some ways how I can get this problem resolved.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class DiyVector
{
  public:
    DiyVector()
    {
        arr = new T[1];
        arrSize = 0;
        index = 0;
        capacity = 1;
    }
    ~DiyVector()
    {
        delete[] arr;
    }

    T& at(unsigned int index) const
    {
        if (index >= arrSize || index < 0)
        {
            throw OutOfRange{};
        }
        else
        {
            return arr[index];
        }
    }

    unsigned int size() const
    {
        return arrSize;
    }

    void pushBack(const T& item)
    {
         if (arrSize == capacity)
         {
            arrTemp = new T[capacity += 1];

            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < capacity; ++i)
            {
                arrTemp[i] = arr[i];
            }

            delete[] arr;
            capacity++;
            arr = arrTemp;
         }

         arr[arrSize] = item;
         arrSize++;

    }

    void popBack()
    {
        if (arrSize == 0)
        {
            throw OutOfRange{};
        }
        else
        {
            arrSize--;
        }
    }

    void erase(unsigned int index)
    {
        if (index >= arrSize || index < 0)
        {
            throw OutOfRange{};
        }

        else
        {
            arrTemp = new T[capacity -= 1];

            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < capacity; ++i)
            {
                arrTemp[i] = arr[i];
            }

            delete[] arr;
            capacity--;
            arr = arrTemp;
        }
    }

    void insert(unsigned int index, const T& item)
    {
        if (index >= arrSize || index < 0)
        {
            throw OutOfRange{};
        }

        else if (index == capacity)
        {
            pushBack(item);
        }
        else if (0 <= index && index <= size())
        {
            arr[index] = item;
        }
    }

    class OutOfRange{};

private:
    unsigned int arrSize;
    unsigned int capacity;
    unsigned int index;
    T* arr;
    T* arrTemp;
  };
```

Comment: did you mean `capacity += 1;` instead of `capacity + 1;` in `push_back`?

Comment: I'm creating a new array that can exactly hold one more element. That's why I used capacity + 1

Comment: @debrisoroids `capacity + 1` does nothing, because you don't assign the value to anything. So you have to save `capacity = capacity + 1` or in short `capacity += 1`

Comment: Okay I changed it now but the problem still lies the same :(

Comment: `index` is never initialized in the constructor, so using it becomes undefined behavior. There are multiple fundamental bugs in the shown code; and likely other bugs too, that a complete analysis will uncover. You need to learn how to use a debugger, so you can debug your own code and see everything that's wrong with it. stackoverflow.com isn't really a substitute for your own debugger. This is what a debugger is for. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer. Have you yet used a debugger with this code, and if not, why not?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm really new to coding. I'm going to take your advice and improve my code.

Comment: And why exactly "`if (index >= arrSize || index < 0)`" appears in nearly every method, even this one, for which it makes absolutely no sense? This looks like something that was robo-copied into every method, without fully understanding the need for it; then, to make the compilation error go away `index` gets added as a class member; but without fully understanding the reason for the compilation error. When you're looking at a compilation error you don't understand, the right thing to do is to figure it out, not search for it on the Internet, and assume that the first explanation, applies here.

Comment: @debrisoroids If you are new to coding, I wouldn't recommend to start with an implementation of vector. Real vectors are quite complicated and involve advanced beasts such as _placement new_, `std::move_if_noexcept`, etc. There are even discussions about whether vectors are implementable according to C++ rules (e.g., treating objects created in an uninitialized memory as arrays). Even your implementation will have big problems with _exceptions_, which you do not seem to care about.

Comment: @DanielLangr I'm taking a programming course on c++ and I was given this task to complete. I know my code is still not neat but I'm learning still.

Comment: @debrisoroids All right, this make sense (though I don't like such assignments that basically force you to implement a very bad version of vector). Anyway, note that `index` cannot be `<0` when its type is `unsigned int`.

Comment: A "programming course on C++" is unlikely to be starting with templates, and other advanced topics, right from the beginning. By the time I started learning templates, I no longer described myself as "new to coding".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Then that could possibly mean I'm weak at coding, which I don't deny as well but hey, it's not like I'm not trying to overcome my weak sides of programming.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use arrays in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters this check in some member functions (for example including `insert`)

```
if (index >= arrSize || index < 0)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^
```

does not make sense because the variable `index` declared as having the type unsigned int never can be negative. So you may exclude the second sub-condition of the if statement.

In the function `pushBack` in this loop

```
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < capacity; ++i)
        {
            arrTemp[i] = arr[i];
        }
```

subsritute `capacity` for `arrSize`.

Also remove the statement

```
capacity++;
```

because capacity was already incremented in this statement

```
arrTemp = new T[capacity += 1];
```

Within the function `insert` change this code snippet

```
    else if (index == capacity)
    {
        pushBack(item);
    }
    else if (0 <= index && index <= size())
    {
        arr[index] = item;
    }
```

to

```
    if ( arrSize <= index )
    {
        pushBack(item);
    }
    else
    {
        arr[index] = item;
    }
```

And you may remove the data member

```
unsigned int index;
```

because it is not used.

Pay attention to that the member function erase is also incorrect. At least there is no need to reallocate the array and change its capacity. And again there are twice capacity is decremented.

```
     arrTemp = new T[capacity -= 1];
     //...
     capacity--;
```

that is the function has the same defects as the function pushBack. And in the loop you are coping the erased element.

Comment: I would add a note that this solution based on OP's code may increase capacity with each `pushBack`, which would be very inefficient. It would be better to, e.g., double the capacity instead.

Comment: @DanielLangr I updated the post relative to the redundant data member index.

Comment: but for the insert member function, I'm throwing OutOfRange error if (index >= arrSize)

Comment: @debrisoroids But that `index` refers to the parameter of `insert`, not to `index` member variable.

Comment: @DanielLangr I know about doubling the capacity but my task has this limitation where my task mentions that we have to increase the capacity exactly by one just to store one more element.

Comment: @debrisoroids But in any case the capacity shall not be decreased two times in the function erase.

Comment: @debrisoroids Ok, another strange requirement ;-)